# Tabbed Win 7 Explorer interface that doesn't look like garbage?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm looking for an Explorer plug-in (not a standalone app) that gives me tabs and integrates very nicely into the Windows 7 look and feel.

What I'm looking for is something along the lines of [Total Finder for Mac](http://smokingapples.com/software/reviews/totalfinder-mac/).

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Explorer add-in to give tabbed functionality in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/62058/windows-explorer-add-in-to-give-tabbed-functionality-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I've found is [Clover](http://ejie.me/clover-wings-for-explorer), which is almost exactly like Google Chrome for Windows Explorer

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it myself, but [Windows Double Explorer](http://wde.codeplex.com/) might be useful to you.

According to [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5475004/double-explorer-adds-dual+pane-file-browsing-to-windows)

> Double Explorer adds tabbed browsing and a dual-pane view for navigating your files, but unlike a full replacement application, it embeds a normal Windows Explorer screen into each pane.

Answer (score 0):

There is [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/), which looks pretty good. The only issue is that it isn't fully compatible with Windows 7. There are [various discussions](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/forum/t-101934/windows-7) on what works and what doesn't, and how to overcome most of the problems.

It is the only decent one I've come across so far that works (marginally) with Windows 7.

Comment: Wouldn't recommend QTTabBar from my personal experiences.

Comment: @Sathya: Me too, I won't recommend it :) .