# How do I close/prevent duplicate windows in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I often end up with a lot of duplicate windows, it would be nice to have an utility to close them, leaving just one of a kind. Or it could put an opened instance forward should I try to access open one more. For example, I could wind up with five "c:\foo\bar" open, I only need one, the extra five just take up screen real estate and create clutter in the task bar.

Comment: So you're suggesting is that if you have two Explorer windows open, one pointing at `c:\foo` and one pointing someplace else, that if you navigate the 2nd one to `c:\foo` it should, instead, just pop the one already pointing at `c:\foo` in front of the one your are currently using?  What if you need two `c:\foo\` views at once?

Comment: Which option do you have chosen under Tools->Folder Options->Browse Folders?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I never need two views, probably. Closing the dupes would probably work just as good. As for the option, it's the default one, "open in same window", the problem is I just tend to browse to the same folders many times.

Comment: You do know there's a red "X", and Alt-F4 available to close windows you are done with right? :) (kidding).  Actually I have a suggestion that might work a little better for you.  I'll post it as an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a utility or settings that will allow Explorer to work as you'd like.

My suggestion is to get yourself a tabbed browser add-on for Explorer, that way you only have one window, with a bunch of tabs.  Personally I use [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/):

[image: QTTabBar]

It adds quite a few other useful features you may want to check out as well (ie: Folder expansion on hover, etc.).

Check out these SU questions for more suggestions on tabbed browser add-ons:

- [Windows Explorer add-in to give tabbed functionality in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/62058/windows-explorer-add-in-to-give-tabbed-functionality-in-windows-7)
- [Tabbed Win 7 Explorer interface that doesn't look like garbage?](https://superuser.com/questions/102214/tabbed-win-7-explorer-interface-that-doesnt-look-like-garbage)

If you just want to outright replace Explorer with one that perhaps has your functionality   requirements, here's a question with some ideas:

- https://superuser.com/questions/90/replacement-for-windows-explorer

Comment: Thanks! I'd rather not replace the shell. I'll probably end up writing a script to kill the extra instances. Sigh.

Comment: Well the tabbed browser add-on's aren't shell replacements. ;)

Comment: @xxzoid I know it's been a long time but did you have any luck with the script?