# Can explorer close "duplicate" windows automatically?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I've got the exact same problem as described here [How do I close/prevent duplicate windows in Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/358499/how-do-i-close-prevent-duplicate-windows-in-windows-explorer)

I wish explorer could close the duplicate window (the other one, not the one that has focus) immediately when I navigate to the relevant folder. Is there another workflow (without installing new software) that I could learn in order to prevent it? Maybe..using favorites and never opening new explorer windows?